# How to get contact creation time

Tags: android, contacts

I want to get the contact creation time, not CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP, but I can not find how to get it, anyone know how to get it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  There's no column in the SqlLite database for "date created", so there's really no certain way to know when that row was inserted.  Sorry :(